Query on Java coding conventions. Assigning fields using 'this' keyword
Apologies in advance if I use the incorrect terminology in my post. Feel free to correct me if I have worded anything incorrectly.
I am currently studying a module at Open University and have received a marked assignment back where I have lost a couple of marks for coding style.
As it is not allowed to post assignment questions/answers online, I have written an example code which is written in the same format.
public class MyClass {
    private String carMake;
    private String carModel;

    public MyClass(String carMake, String carModel) {
        this.carMake= carMake;
        this.carModel= carModel;
    }
}


I was advised instead of using the this keyword, to have different paramater and field names. Like below:
public class MyClass {
    private String carMake;
    private String carModel;

    public MyClass(int aCarMake, int aCarModel) {
        carMake= aCarMake;
        carModel= aCarModel;
    }
}


I have been studying Java for over a year before I actually started this module and from what I had learned, the way I have done this is standard practice.
Before questioning the tutor, I wanted to make sure I wasn't mistaken, so I tried finding some information on Oracle's website.
I found the below:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html
Which, although it doesn't directly talk about assigning the fields, it does use the this keyword when setting fields in one of the examples at the bottom of the page.
I then also found this:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-declarations.html#381
Which shows the tutor's method of using differently named parameters and fields (also at the bottom of the page)
I'm not really too worried about the marks, rather I just want to know which way would be more widely used/acceptable.

Coding styles are always opinionated and therefore off-topic as point of discussion on Stack Overflow. That being said: "I was advised instead of using the this keyword, to have different paramater and field names." - this is very atypical. It is common to use this.foo = foo in c'tors and/or setters.

maybe not the best examples, since fieldA is as descritive as aFieldA, there is no real advantage of any of the two options -- if you had a field, for example, age then maybe you would prefer the constructor also using age instead of something like theAge or aAge (sure it is a mater of preferences; and a bit of usability like being able to search for the word age without having to remember to search for alternatives)

Hello spectation, welcome, The teacher's word is sacred (unless you want to fail), the choice of style is something personal, I prefer to use different names... and I save the this., but these are things of no importance, although you will find “Talibans” who will take you to court for not following the conventions, waste your time trying to make your code optimal, the rest...

You are right and they are wrong ;)

I'd agree that this is the more usual route.  If there's a good alternate name for the parameter, sure use that other name.  But many times there isn't a good name, and adding an underscore or a random letter or number is not good style.  Use this unless there is a clear, good alternative.  That said, for this teacher (or this manager, or this senior engineer) you should expect to comply with their conventions.

I've been a Java developer for a long time and would disagree with your tutor.

Thank you for the help guys. Regarding the example, it was quite vague. A better example would be String carMake and Stringg carModel for the field names & types

It seems very poor practice to deduct marks from an assignment based on coding style (as long as the style conforms to some widely accepted convention).

Your tutor is recommending a very old convention, which dates back to the earliest days of object-oriented development.  One reason people don't do that anymore is that parameters are harder to distinguish at a glance when they all start with the same letter.
